# Run xslt from macro

Tags: xslt, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I am going to make a xslt from data in Calc.
Really I need to replace some data in ready xml files.
I supposed to use a RegEx but sometimes I need to add/delete more siblings.
So XSLT would be a good here.
I played with xslt filters, it works, but not enough for me.
I'd do it from macros.
I think it is possible, but I have not found any template or even comprehensive docs.
I'm new for UNO.
Can you help me to find any appropriate template for BASIC or C++ or any.
Or reference to any docs concerning.
Thank you.

Comment: I dont understand exactly, by what means do you want to make the xslt transform? Built-in from oocalc but on xml files in the filesystem?

Comment: yes, I want to use built-in oocalc xslt processor to make/modify external xml files based on the data in calc sheet. I suppose it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Java and Python have good XML parsing and regular expression libraries.  I typically use [xml.dom.minidom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) and [re](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html) for Python.  See [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/Writing_Macros) for "Hello World" type macros in these languages.

Basic does not have its own library, although there is an UNO service that provides a SAX style parser.  See section 5.38 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php) for an example.

For C++, I typically avoid a lot of string processing or macro writing because it is a lower level language.  However there are probably XML parsing libraries available, and macros can be written with some effort.

Comment: I suppose I can use XSLT UNO service and trying to find a sample or information about it.

Comment: I am not aware of any XSLT UNO services.  If you specifically need an XSLT processor, one option is to download and use [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/).  That is what OpenOffice uses for its filters.  But I think it would be easier for a macro to modify XML files with an XML parsing library as mentioned in my answer.  Or use Java, which I believe has [its own XSLT processing library](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html).

Comment: I found XSLT a very mighty thing so trying to use it. To use external XSLT processor I will need to prepare input xml files I suppose, not right out of calc data. Thank you for your help, Jim, it's helpful.